# How, to show my output in vertically in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to show my "output" in vertically way, here i use "end function" but not working in my code.
How can i solve it?

**Here, in my output code**

```
print (",".join(l), end = " ")
```

**And Here is my full code**

```
l=[]
for i in range(2000, 3201):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%5!=0):
        l.append(str(i))
```

**I also give my output**

```
C:\Users\DCL\PycharmProjects\Exercise\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/DCL/PycharmProjects/Exercise/problem-1.py
2002,2009,2016,2023,2037,2044,2051,2058,2072,2079,2086,2093,2107,2114,2121,2128,2142,2149,2156,2163,2177,2184,2191,2198,2212,2219,2226,2233,2247,2254,2261,2268,2282,2289,2296,2303,2317,2324,2331,2338,2352,2359,2366,2373,2387,2394,2401,2408,2422,2429,2436,2443,2457,2464,2471,2478,2492,2499,2506,2513,2527,2534,2541,2548,2562,2569,2576,2583,2597,2604,2611,2618,2632,2639,2646,2653,2667,2674,2681,2688,2702,2709,2716,2723,2737,2744,2751,2758,2772,2779,2786,2793,2807,2814,2821,2828,2842,2849,2856,2863,2877,2884,2891,2898,2912,2919,2926,2933,2947,2954,2961,2968,2982,2989,2996,3003,3017,3024,3031,3038,3052,3059,3066,3073,3087,3094,3101,3108,3122,3129,3136,3143,3157,3164,3171,3178,3192,3199 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why do you join the numbers using a comma if you want to print them vertically? You should join them using a newline (`"\n"`).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print("\n".join(l))
```

Or:

```py
for item in l:
    print(item)
```

If you do not specifiy the `end` argument, `print` automatically uses a line separator after having printed the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use \n to create a new line:

```
l=[]
for i in range(2000, 3201):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%5!=0):
        l.append(str(i))

print (",\n".join(l))
```

gives:

```
2002,
2009,
2016,
2023,
2037,
2044,
2051,
2058,
```

(I truncated it so as not to fill the page here).
Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use newline character (i.e., '\n') like this:

```
l=[]
for i in range(2000, 3201):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%5!=0):
        l.append(str(i))

print ("\n".join(l), end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print inside the `for` loop.

```
l=[]
for i in range(2000, 3201):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%5!=0):
        l.append(str(i));print (i)
```